# Yum Update Doesn't Work

Tags: centos, yum, vps, centos-5

I've started a fresh VPS with CentOS 5. As the first step, wanted to update all packages so I executed `yum update`

It showed the list of packages to be upgraded - 86 in total, 98 Mb download size.

Then when in prompts: `Is this ok [y/N]:`

I type `y`, press Enter, and it gives this output:

```
Existing on user Command
Complete!
```

Nothing updates - when I run `yum update` repeatedly, same thing happens over and over.

I did all of:

```
yum clean all
yum clean metadata
yum clean dbcache
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a strange bug.

You can still update it using either `-y` argument:

```
yum -y update
```

(it will stop prompting that)

or a `yes` tool:

```
yes | yum update
```

(it will always enter "y")

Comment: Tried the 1st option, it worked. I hope the bug itself is fixed in the update that came in. Thanks for a quick response!

Comment: After working on the server for some more, I noticed that even the commands like ``rm`` don't work when you submit ``y``. Turns out it's the Java browser based SSH client provided by the provider. When I switched to PuTTY, everything worked fine.